# How can I insert codes or do something if the app detected an altbeacon with Pibeacon default UUID and the minor or id3 is 1?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm a newbie in android development and I am using altbeacon library and the reference app for altbeacons we also have a 2 Pibeacons....... the reference works fine and able to detect both beacons ...I want to do something if the app detected a specific beacon ...for example i want to display a string if I detected a beacon in near proximity....the first 2 if statement works fine but if I added a condition to determine which beacon is in near proximity the 3rd if statement does not work....the first beacon minor is 1 and the 2nd is 2

```
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
    if (beacons.size() > 0) {
        for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
            if(BeaconProximity.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()) == "Near"){
                logToDisplay("Hello");              
            }

            if(BeaconProximity.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()) == "Immediate"){
                logToDisplay("Hi");             
            }

            if(BeaconProximity.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()) == "Near" && beacon.getId3 == Identifier.parse("1"){

            logToDisplay("World");              
            }
       }
    }
```

if I only display beacon.getId3 and Identifier.parse("1") like this code logToDisplay(beacon.getId3()+"="+Identifier.parse("1") it will output 1=1 
they are equal but if I make that a condition ... It does not work ...so I dont know whats wrong or  am I missing something or Is there another way to insert a command or codes if I detected a specific beacon in near,far,immediate proximity?

Comment: I'm not familiar with beacons but do you really mean to compare strings with `==`?

Comment: Where do you find BeaconProximity class?

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one issue.  In Java, you can't compare strings with == because that checks to see if they are the exact same *object*.  Instead of:

```
BeaconProximity.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()) == "Near"
```

Use:

```
BeaconProximity.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()).equals("Near")
```

Secondly, I am not sure what the `BeaconProximity` class does.  That is not part of the standard [Android Beacon Library.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/)  If your code does not work with the fix above, you should post the definition of the `BeaconProximity` class.

Comment: I didn't see BeaconProximity in AltBeacon now. Is it obsolete? How can we get an equivalent iOS proximity string now?

Comment: The BeaconProximity class is not part of the library.  If you want to get the equivalent of immediate/near/far on iOS, simply use `beacon.geDistance()`.  A value < 0.5 indicates immediate, from 0.5-3.0 indicates near, and > 3.0 indicates far.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks david.....KB24 is my friend account and I'm the one who ask the question ......I use the beaconhelper class from Beacon Scanner & Logger App by Justin O'Dwyer which also uses  altbeacon library and just rename it to BeaconProximity to determine if the beacon is near,far,immediate or unknown.....actually the 1st code below works fine with just comparing ==

```
    BeaconProximity.getProximityString(beacon.getDistance()) == "Near"
```

but if I add another condition with a code below... it will not work

```
    beacon.getId3() == Identifier.parse("1")
```

and your suggestion solve my problem =) ..... with the code below

```
    beacon.getId3().equals(Identifier.parse("1"))
```

Comment: Yes, it is the same general issue with any object in Java.  You cannot compare different objects for equality with ==, you must use the .equals method.